# XQUERY: Create elements with given names and values

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0, xquery-3.1

I've a requiremnet to generate dynamic elements and values based on two xmls. How can I achieve using XQUERY.

I have data like in two xmls:

```
<td>USERID</td>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>RATING</td>

<id>1</id>
<name>Tom</name>
<grade>A</grade>
```

Expected:

```
<userid>1</userid>
<name>Tom</name>
<rating>A</rating>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the dynamic `element` constructor:

```
let $names  := (<td>USERID</td>, <td>NAME</td>, <td>RATING</td>)
let $values := (<id>1</id>, <name>Tom</name>, <grade>A</grade>)
for $name at $pos in $names
return
  element { fn:lower-case($name) } { fn:data($values[$pos]) }
```

Comment: Thank you @ Florent Georges for a quick response. Is there a way I can use FLOWR instead of position because if any one of the elements is missing in the values then assignment goes wrong. eg: name element is missing then grade value goes into name.